# NServiceBus doesn't start picking up messages until an endpoint is "touched"

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, nservicebus

So when I run my two services locally, I can hit service A which sends a command to service B which picks it up and processes it. Pretty straight forward. However, when I publish these to my web server and I send a request to service A which sends it to service B (I can see the message in service B's queue) but it won't get picked up and processed. I created an endpoint on service B that simply returns an OK response -- if I call this endpoint, effectively "touching" the service, everything kicks on and the messages get processed from that point on.

I figured maybe this had something to do with with late compiling, so I changed the publish to precompile on publish, but I get the same result.

Is there a way to have the service start processing as soon as it is published? Also worth noting that both services are WebAPI 2

Comment: Is there a reason you're hosting your endpoints inside websites/webapi? Could you run them as Windows Services or something similar?

Comment: Simplicity, I thought. The service has many handlers, but it also has a web api. I didn't wanna roll two applications that accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Another option (probably more “standard”) would be to move the “handlers” into a Windows Service instead of a web application.

For this Windows Service you can leverage the NServiceBus Host which will turn a standard class library into a Windows Service for you. They have a good amount of documentation about this here: https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/nservicebus-host/?version=Host_6

I would argue that this is more stable as you can separate the processing of sending commands (Web Application / WebApi) and processing commands / publishing events (NSB Host). The host can sit on the web server itself or you can put these on a different server.

Our default architecture is to have a separate server run our NSB Hosts as you scale web applications and NSB Hosts differently. If you run the NSB Host on the web server, you can get issues where a web app gets too much traffic and takes the NSB Host processing down. You can always start simple with using 1 server for both, monitor the server and then move things around as traffic increases.

Comment: So I've been seeing this a lot too as being the more common way to do it (even mentioned on Particular's site), but I feel like we need a web api to deal with operations that need to be synchronous and having both a web api in iis in addition to a windows service seemed wrong. Thoughts?

Comment: "together" as in being two applications representing the same bounded context

Comment: I guess the other option would be to just add an http listener to the windows service which is what some of our legacy projects did. I'm not sure if my feeling dirty about that is warranted or  not :/

Comment: I had the same feelings at first as I was worried about two different solutions accessing the same data and updates needing to be made to both which might cause problems.

To solve that issue I will put two projects inside of one solution. 1 project being the WebApi (or web app) and the other project being the NSB Host. You can then add an additional library for shared dependencies and keep everything in 1 solution. You can then hook up one build template and have them both deployed on 1 build of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the "right way" to do things, but what I ended up doing is setting up each site to be always running and auto initialize.

- App pool set to "Always Running"
- Website set `preload enabled = true`
- Web.config has webServer entry for application initialization `doAppInitAfterRestart="true"`
- Web Role added to server "Application Initialization"

With those things being set, the deployment process is basically to publish the site and iisreset. If there are better options, I'm still looking :)

Comment: This is the right way to go - instead of doing all this you could also hit your website with an empty GET request to "start" the pool after a deploy, but using App Init works too

Comment: Will [this article about Publishing from Web Applications help?](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/publishing-from-web-applications)